# Magento Integration with Constant Contact

Tags: magento-1.9

when a new user signs up and subscribe newsletter then sends the email to their constant contact list. so how can I integrate ?
I googled and find [This Link.](https://github.com/ExtensionsStore/ConstantContact)

but extension show in `configuration->system->advance` tab,but not shows under the `configuration->general` tab.

Is there any other way to Sync. Magento and Constant contact.

Any kind of help will appreciated.

Comment: After installation, did you clear cache and log out and back into the admin?

Comment: yes i cleared cache and logout after the installation...

Answer (score 0):

We always used the Free Lunch Labs extension when we used Constant Contact, but it's paid.

http://www.freelunchlabs.com/magento-extensions/constant-contact-magento-sync

Comment: this extension works or not?

Comment: because video not play on the youtube... and as well site not secure.

Comment: Yes, the extension works, did you try the openly available demo? You can configure the demo to sync with your account contact lists to see how it works. The video on YouTube also plays without issue, I'm not sure why it's not working for you. Site not secure? The SSL Certificate is valid until 2020. It does, however, appear that they are having issues loading content via their CDN. I don't know, you asked if there was any other way to sync them...